# AFNetwork 2.0 restart failed upload

Tags: ios, video, image-uploading, afnetworking-2

Using AFNetwork 2.0 I'd like to support an async upload operation of a video to my server.
Now, assume that from some reason the upload has failed or timed out, I'd like to attempt another upload attempt. Is there any simple way to just 'restart' that upload attempt?

Assume the following code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration* configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager*       manager       = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
NSURLSessionUploadTask*    uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:req
                                   fromData:data
                                   progress:nil
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response,
                                              id             responseObject,
                                              NSError*       error)
{
    if (error)
    {
         HOW CAN I JUST RESTART THE UPLOAD OPERATION?
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Try calling the function again with the parameters that is needed for your function.